# API/http-request in Angular Universal throws "404 not found" in Docker Image

Tags: angular, docker, angular-universal, angular-http-interceptors

I have an (external developed) Angular application, which includes also Angular Universal. There are already two different targets / API domains built in this project (referred to as api-url-1 and api-url-2) and I added a third one (referred to as new-api-url).
Therefore I added:

**proxy.config.json:**

```
{
"/api-1": {
    "target": "https://api-url-1",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  },
  "/api-2": {
    "target":  "https://api-url-2",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  },
  "/new-api": {
    "target":  "https://new-api-url",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "pathRewrite": { "^/new-api":  ""},
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

In **universal.interceptor.ts** and **server.ts** I added the same lines of code as the existing API adressed had just with the customized names, so that "localhost:4200/new-api/xyz" becomes to "new-api-url/xyz".

This already works when I run the Angular project with `npm start` on localhost in the browser - there everything is fine.

But now I wanted to build a Docker image and container out from it - and there, the new API is not working - the others do.

I built the project with `npm run build:ssr` (also tried already `build:ssr-deploy` with baseUrl ./)

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14.15.5-alpine3.13

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/
COPY proxy.conf.json /usr/src/app/
COPY ./node_modules /usr/src/app/node_modules
COPY ./dist /usr/src/app/dist

ENV PORT=80
EXPOSE $PORT

CMD [ "npm", "run", "serve:ssr" ]
```

When I build the image and run the container, the original two APIs work, so when I inspect the network in the browser the request URL says "localhost:1234/api-1/xyz" with status 200.

But for my added API it says "localhost:1234/new-api/abc" with status 404 not found.
As I tested the request in a new browser tab with the real URL instead of "localhost" and this is working, it must be something missing during the build process?
Unfortunately I couldn't find answers in the documentations yet.
Happy if someone might have an idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error:
Apparently I defined in proxy.conf.json a "pathRewrite" for the new-api, but I forgot to add the same in the server.ts, as I was not aware that these two files do not work together.

**server.ts corrected:**

```
  server.use('/api-1', createProxyMiddleware({target: proxyTarget, changeOrigin: true, logLevel: 'info'}));
  server.use('/api-2', createProxyMiddleware({target: proxyCmsTarget, changeOrigin: true, logLevel: 'info'}));
  server.use('/new-api', createProxyMiddleware({target: proxyTargetGls, changeOrigin: true, logLevel: 'debug', pathRewrite: { '^/new-api':  ''}}));
```